# Typescript modules and systemjs. Instantiate class from inline script

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I am transpiling a typescript module to javascript with the system module option. I am executing this in a browser.

I am able to consume this module when the code to initialize the module class generated by typescript is also loaded using systemjs system.import.

How can i make the class which is part of a module available from javascript code not loaded through systemjs?  E.g. embeded javascript in the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **SystemJS** to import the module in Javascript.

Assuming you have a module named **app.ts** that exports a variable named **value**.

app.ts:

```
export let value = 'ABCASF';
```

In a script tag you can write:

```js
System.import('app.js').then(function(appModule) {
  console.log(appModule.value);
}, console.error.bind(console));
```

Keep in mind that the module name you have to give to **System.import** might vary according to your setup.

TypeScript classes get transpiled to ES5 functions so you can make use of them in javascript this way.

example.ts:

```js
export class Example {
  constructor(public someValue: string, private someOtherValue: number) {

  }

  public method() {
    return this.someOtherValue;
  }
}
```

And in the script tag this way:

```js
  System.import('example.js').then(function(example) {
    // Example class is a function on the module 
    // use new to make a new instance
    var value = new example.Example('a', 5);

    // work as usual 
    console.log(value.method());

  }, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: I might not have made it clear.  I am loading the module with systemjs.  I want to use a class from that module from a page inline javascript.

Comment: @user3591122 hah.. then my first answer would've been the correct one! I misunderstood.

Comment: @user3591122 I edited the answer again, does that work for you? :)

Comment: if not I can make an answer where you export a class specifically.

Comment: Great, that works and I upvoted your answer although that wont show until my rep is 15

Comment: @user3591122 if it answers your issue it's best you mark the answer as the correct one, so other people will know. :)