# javascript code compiled in typescript is not found in plain html

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use a typescript class in js. But could not find it in js code. I can use it in typescript but not in the javascript.

**animal.ts**

```
export class Animal {

    name:string;    

    constructor(name:string) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public run(){
        console.log(this.name+':Animal runs.');
    }

    public eat(){
        console.log(this.name+':Animal eats.');
    }

    public sleep(){
        console.log(this.name+':Animal sleeps.');
    }
}

//TEST 
let mouse:Animal = new Animal("Alfred");
let cat:Animal = new Animal("Gustavo");

if(mouse !=null && cat!=null){
    mouse.run();
    cat.sleep();
}else{
    console.log("ERROR cat or mouse  NULL");
}
```

**animal.js**

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";
var Animal = (function () {
    function Animal(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Animal.prototype.run = function () {
        console.log(this.name + ':Animal runs.');
    };
    Animal.prototype.eat = function () {
        console.log(this.name + ':Animal eats.');
    };
    Animal.prototype.sleep = function () {
        console.log(this.name + ':Animal sleeps.');
    };
    return Animal;
}());
exports.Animal = Animal;
//TEST 
var mouse = new Animal("Alfred");
var cat = new Animal("Gustavo");
if (mouse != null && cat != null) {
    mouse.run();
    cat.sleep();
}
else {
    console.log("ERROR cat or mouse  NULL");
}
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

**compilation of ts in js with  browserify**

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var tsify = require('tsify');

browserify()
    .add('src/test/typescript/animal.ts')
    .plugin(tsify, { noImplicitAny: true })
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function (error) { console.error(error.toString()); })
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

**build command of ts in js**

```
node animal.build.js >  src/test/typescript/animal.js
```

**animal.html**
This file is an example of use of animal.js that contains Animal class.
The animal.js is loaded, but can't find Animal class from the html context!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <title>Animal test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="animal.js"></script>
  <script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("html ready");
        console.log("now trying animal");

        var a = new Animal('titi');
            if(a === undefined || a ===null){
                console.log("ERROR a not defined!");
            }
            else{
                a.run();
            }
     });  




  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Google Chrome console output of animal.html**

Navigated to

```
file:///C:/dev/git/wscommerce/src/test/typescript/animal/animal.html
animal.js:8 Alfred:Animal runs.
animal.js:14 Gustavo:Animal sleeps.
animal.html:13 html ready
animal.html:14 now trying animal
animal.html:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: Animal is not defined(anonymous function) @ animal.html:16i @ jquery.min.js:2j.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2
```

**Problem**
You can see in the chrome console output that from within the typescript generated js, I can use the Animal class. But from animal.html, I can't find the   reference. I encounter a scope / build problem on typescript.My target environnement webserver will be tomcat. I will package this scripts into a plain war. I do not want to deploy a nodejs server.

Comment: that's because you are probably compiling the typescript code to match some module loader, so you need a module loader to load your code.

Comment: also, asking the same question again will not guarantee you an answer. :)

Comment: how  can i perform that can you give me a module loader that is lightweight and does not need to install node server on target environnement (will run in a simple tomcat server)

Comment: If loading a class from js is what you are looking after I answered a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313093/typescript-modules-and-systemjs-instantiate-class-from-inline-script

Comment: it might be the same root problem, I'm trying to get helped and simplified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that does not requieres dependencies, is :

**1. add modules in all file**

```
module Rizze{ // ts code ....
}
```

**2. removing require clauses in ts files**
This will imply using Module.Class.function in order to use a references module.

**3.1 build resources : gulpfile**

```
 //gulp 

var gulp = require('gulp');

// for ts compil
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');


// For minification and offuscation
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

//css minification
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var paths = {
    js: 'src/main/**/*.ts',
    css: 'src/main/**/*.css',
    alljs: 'dist/js/all.js',
}
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', { sortOutput: true });

gulp.task('default',  function() {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

**3.2 build ressource: tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target":  "ES5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "charset":"UTF-8",      
        "noImplicitAny" : true  ,
        "outFile": "all.js"
    }
    ,

     "filesGlob": [     
        "src/main/typescript/*.ts",
        "!src/main/typescript/lib/**/*.ts"
    ]

}
```

**With this config, it works without node, and without requirejs in a plain html/js environnement.**

Answer (score 1):

`Animal` class is declared inside anonymous function and is also declared as a module, then external code will not see the Animal class.
If you want to use Animal class you need to require Animal class:

```
var Animal = require('Animal');
var newAnimal = new Animal('test');
```

Comment: will try that one now, using requirejs

Comment: requirejs is part of node delivery. This workaround adds a dependency in my project.

Comment: for that, I will not accept as solution  this workaroud. I don't want to add  dependencies to my project. The less dependencies I have, the better I live. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, in the chrome console be sure the animal.js is loading and it's loading fast enough to be called from your html code.

Comment: The order of the logs suggests the animal.js file gets interpreted before the 2nd <script> statement. The problem is with the generated code. :)

Comment: yes I've modified the html in order to take this advice in consideration. @toskv   is right!