# Understanding TypeScript and SystemJS WITHOUT Angular

Tags: typescript, module, systemjs, typescript2.0, es6-modules

I've been researching and doing simple "hello worlds" with TypeScript recently. There is something I think I can't wrap my head around and that is how to use System.js with TypeScript. Every single tutorial or demo out there on the internet is about Angular2 and I don't want to get involved with Angular 2 yet.

As an example, I have the following project structure:

```
RootFolder
| 
| _lib
| ...... ts (where .ts files are)
|
| components (where compiled .js files are)
| libraries
| ......... systemjs (where system.js is)
|
| index.html
| tsconfig.json
```

My tsconfig.json file is looking like:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./components"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./_lib/ts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

TypeScript compilation works as expected and there are no problems with that. I have created a simple class named "Alerter" contains the following code:

```
//alerter.ts
class Alerter {
    showMessage(): void {
        alert("Message displayed.");
    }
}

export default Alerter
```

And an app.ts (which is my "main" application file) with the following code:

```
//app.ts
import Alerter from "./alerter";

console.log("app.js included & executed");

function test() {
    console.log("test called");
    const alt = new Alerter();
    alt.showMessage();
};
```

And in my index.html I just want to import this app.js with System.js and simply want to call "test" function from the console. But it does not work. No matter what I did I simply can't access the function. I see the first console.log line being executed but when I try to call test() from chrome console it is undefined.

If I remove the "alerter" class dependency from my main.ts everything works. Because compiled app.js only contains console.log calls and the function definition.

Here is my System.js calls in index.html

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        "components": {
            defaultExtension: "js"
        }
    }
});

System.import("components/app");
```

I'm really desperate now and think I should simply go back to Jquery days. This is so simple yet can't make it work.

Comment: I made a simple TS + SystemJS project setup for a presentation maybe it will help you. https://github.com/Toskv/talk.timjs.typescript/tree/master/modules/live

Comment: @toskv Thank you it's really helpful so far. I'm still inspecting but already gave me good insight.

Comment: if you want to access the function from index.html you'll have to load to export it  so you can use it once the module loading is finished. System.import returns a promise and the response will contain the module you ask for. :)

Comment: this might be helpful in understanding the my last comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313093/typescript-modules-and-systemjs-instantiate-class-from-inline-script/36318745#36318745

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see what's going on here. This is related to both proper usage of TypeScript `export` keyword and SystemJS.

From your description you basically want to use SystemJS to import a JavaScript file similarly to using just the `<script>` tag and then use its global defined functions.

But this means you need to be aware of how TypeScript compiles your files. The documentation at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html says:

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module.

This is what you're doing. The `app.ts` file has one `import` and the `alerter.ts` file has one `export` statement so these both are going to be compiled as modules. Then from your `tsconfig.json` I see you're using the `system` format (however, it doesn't matter here).

One major benefit of modules is that they don't leak any global objects outside the of their scope. So when you call `System.import("components/app")` the `test()` function exists only within that module. But you can export the function and call it after the module is loaded:

This means you need to export the function first:

```
// app.ts
export function test() {
  ...
};
```

Then `System.import()` returns a Promise that is resolved with the module exports object so we can call the `test()` method there.

```
System.import("components/app").then(function(m) {
  m.test();
});
```

This really works as you expect.

However, it looks like you wanted to define the `test()` function globaly. In such case you need to define the function on the `window` global object yourself:

```
// app.ts
function test() {
  ...
}
declare const window;
window.test = test;
```

Now you can use it whenever you want after importing the package:

```
System.import("components/app").then(function(m) {
  test();
});
```

SystemJS has multiple ways to manipulate with global objects but I don't think there's any easier way to use them when your imported package has dependencies that need to be resolved as well (otherwise have a look at this but it's not your use-case https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#exports).

Comment: Excellent explanation! Exporting my test() function solved the problem like you said and I got the idea of how it works thanks to your answer. One thing though, what is the best practice to include my own "local / internal" modules to each other? Should I always and always implement "each file is a module" and use import / export or <reference  path="..."> is enough?

Comment: @Alaminut I think `<reference path="...">` is used only by the compiler and doesn't generate import statements so the code will won't work. The `<reference path="...">` was used in older version of TypeScript to tell the compiler about your `*d.ts` files. I don't think I has any common usage now so I'd stick to using only `import` and `export`.